# Is this proof that $\tan a$ is transcendental correct?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, transcendental-numbers

First, a proof that $\sin a$ is transcendental, where $a$ is algebraic not zero. Given that,

$$e^{ia}=\cos a + i\sin a$$

if $\sin a$ were algebraic, then $\cos a = \pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2a}\:$  is also algebraic, implying that

$$e^{ia}=\pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2a} + i\sin a$$

is algebraic, but $e^{ia}$ is transcendental (Lindemann theorem). Doing the same thing we can prove that $\cos a$ is transcendental.

If

$$\tan a = \frac{\sin a}{\cos a}$$

were algebraic, then $\sin a / \cos a$ is algebraic, implying that $\sin a$ and $\cos a$ are both algebraic, but this is false.

EDIT: Thanks! I get it now.

Comment: Wouldn't this be false if something like $\frac{e\sqrt{2}}{e}=\sqrt{2}$ happened?  The result is algebraic, but the terms in the fraction aren't.

Comment: @Randall is correct, the argument given is incorrect.  You need to do something like this... if $\tan a$ were algebraic, then $e^{ia}$ would be the solution of a quadratic equation with algebraic coefficients, so $e^{ia}$ would also be algebraic.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely possible for the quotient of transcendental numbers to be algebraic. Rather than that, you are looking for a relation like $$1+\tan^2 x=\frac1{\cos^2 x}$$

Comment: +1... So if $\tan x$ exists and is algebraic then $ 0\ne \cos x$ and $\cos x$ is algebraic because  $(\cos x)^{-2}=1+\tan^2 x$ is. And then $\sin x$ is also, so $e^{ix}$ is, so $x=0$ or $x$ is not algebraic.

Comment: My edit was for a trivial typo.

Answer (score 2):

From
$$
\tan a = \frac{\sin a}{\cos a}
$$
we get
$$
\tan a = \frac{e^{ia} - e^{-ia}}{i(e^{ia}+e^{-ia})}
$$
Solve this for $e^{ia}$.  We conclude that $e^{ia}$ is the solution of a quadratic equation with algebraic coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

It might be clearer if you said something like

$$\sin \alpha = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\tan^2 \alpha}}}$$

making it clearer that if  $\tan \alpha$ is algebraic then so too is $\sin \alpha$